raspberry pi 4 not booting act led flash 2 or 3 time
is there a possibility that the raspberry pi 4 system lock will not boot after overheating?  If so, how do I reset it?

I've never heard of such a thing, no.  Actually doing damage by overheating is hard, though, unless you have disabled throttling.  Worth consideration: the XY problem.

With power, hdmi and no sd card - do you get the diagnostics screen?

Check it thoroughly for power issues- use a meter to measure its voltage.
